# How to create a dynamic list of labels from a frequently updated list in Kivy

Tags: dynamic, kivy, label

I am trying to build a structure that will have multiple columns of data that will be updated and have to scroll together.

The overall application has multiple pages, etc. The label-building part of it does appear to work as it is putting the "hello world" in the right part of the page.  But, it appears to be populating all of the data right on top of each other, even though I am using the "index" property.  Here are some some snippets from the py and kv files:

```
class RV(FloatLayout):  
    def re_build(self):
        label_list = [Label(text = "Label {}".format(x)) for x in range(20)]
        for count, x in enumerate(label_list):
            self.add_widget(Label(text='Hello World'), index = count)'
        


class MainScreen(Screen):  
    pass

class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
    pass 

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return ScreenManagement()


if __name__ == '__main__': 
      
    # Here the class MyApp is initialized 
    # and its run() method called. 
    TestApp().run()
```

```
<ScreenManagement>:
    padding: 10
    MainScreen:
        id: main_screen
        name: 'main_screen'

<MainScreen>:
    GridLayout:
        rows:3
        cols:1


        Button:
            size_hint: 1, None
            height: 50
            text: "just setting up"
            on_press:
                root.ids.rv.re_build()

        
        RV:

            id: rv

        

        GridLayout:
            rows:3
            cols:2
            size_hint : None, None
            CheckBox:
                active:False
            Label:
                text: 'item 1'
            CheckBox:
                active:False
            Label:
                text: 'item 2'
            CheckBox:
                active:False
            Label:
                text: 'item 3'
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
self.add_widget(Label(text='Hello World'), index = count)
```

is adding the `Label` to your `RV` class, which is a `FloatLayout`. In a `FloatLayout`, the `index` in the `add_widget()` call has no effect on the position of the `Label`, it only affects the order of drawing the Labels. Try using a different `Layout` as the base class for your `RV` class. Some examples that will position their children according to `index` are `GridLayout`, `BoxLayout`, and `StackLayout`.